# The correct way to update progress in notification (android)

Tags: notifications, progress, android-notification-bar

I've checked a lot of websites and all of them were using:

```
notificationManager.notify(id,builder.build());
```

So I thought it's the right way and went for it in my app.The result proved me wrong.This works,however if you drag up and down the notification panel while progress is updating,the notification gets jumpy.And that's not the way the other apps do this.So I want to know how to do this.

What I've tried:

```
Using asynTask
Handler with runnable
```

Those have no effects as I thought they won't but anyway I tried them.There's nothing wrong with my progress updating and it's efficient and doesn't even send a percent twice (only sends a new value if it's changed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a quite time,And nobody has answered.So I give a workaround.The point with my case is server is too fast and even big files get uploaded too fast.So progress goes too fast.Since human eyes basically can not process as fast as we update the Progress,It's Okay to have the progress an interval of 1 second or something.You can use 0.4s.(That's proved to be a good number for humans).